# North American joke: “What do you call Halloween boner?'”

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, jokes, halloween

I searched everywhere to find out what this joke means:

> "What do you call a Halloween boner?"
>   "Petrified wood!"

Wood is probably slang for boner. Maybe erectile dysfunction, but I still don't understand anything here.

English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, *boner* cannot function as a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun). Insert *a* to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

Both *boner* and *wood* are vulgar synonyms for an erection.  The joke (such as it is) consists of a play on the word *petrified*, which literally means turned to stone -- petrified wood refers to trees that have had their organic matter replaced with minerals.  But it also has come to mean frightened into immobility.  And frightening things are associated with Halloween.

Addendum:  Those who would like to see petrified wood may go to the [Petrified Forest National Park](http://www.nps.gov/pefo/) in Arizona, USA.  Those who can't may still wish to go [here](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.americansouthwest.net/arizona/photographs569/black-forest1.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.americansouthwest.net/arizona/petrified_forest/national_park.html&h=338&w=569&tbnid=PjP0M8fCS9ZHFM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=269&usg=__zd9UB8mg373hPF9JS3XrEUQCIHY=&docid=ZOzIf-B8c3s-lM&itg=1).

Comment: And it is a very poor joke.

Comment: Oh, I don't know.  It kinda grows on me.

Comment: @deadrat- ***TMI!***

Comment: @HotLicks : What would you expect? It's a Halloween joke.

Comment: Do zombies eat popcorn with their fingers? *No, they eat the fingers separately.*

Comment: We had a saying years ago, to the effect that when someone was horribly frightened, they were "scared stiff"! It wasn't a double entendre then but seems to be now!

Comment: I vote to close this question on grounds of ill humor.

Comment: +1 for [*petrified wood*](https://www.google.it/search?q=petrified+wood&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CEwQsARqFQoTCJKSj8Lf8cgCFYQIGgod7RMJVA&biw=1366&bih=641) which I did not know about. (I'd post a link to the images)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Done.

Comment: That last link is from http://www.americansouthwest.net/arizona/petrified_forest/national_park.html.

Comment: @TRiG "Those who can should visit the National Park; those who can't, should click on a url"  Is this really unclear?

Comment: @deadrat I just dislike links on the word *here*, but didn't have time to think of an alternative phrasing.

Comment: @TRiG I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I got it. Here is the context: On my FB page, a young couple's bodies were painted as skeletons. It was petrifying, and at the same time, erotic. That joke was a comment for that photo.